# Why E(Y) and not Y in simple linear regression equation?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I was watching this video on YouTube of simple linear regression equation, and he said that E(Y)=Beta0 + Beta1x + elipson, and said that there is a whole distribution for the possible Y values, and hence it's E(Y). I didn't get that why there is a whole distribution for y values, shouldn't it just be Y, because we are already accounting for the errors in elipson. Please help me.

Video Link:https://youtu.be/iAgYLRy7e20
The statement is made 12:40

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a link to the video and at what time in the video the statement is made. YouTube videos of math are not all of uniformly high quality.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I have added the link and time now

Comment: That is not what is stated in the video. It shows (at 11:29), $y = \beta_0+\beta_1x + \epsilon$ and $E(y) = \beta_0+\beta_1x$. You combined these in an incorrect way which was not done in the video.

Comment: Ohhhh, so to account for the error, it is E(Y)?So we can either write y=Beta0+ beta1x+epsilon or E(Y)=Beta0+beta1x and both will be deemed to be correct?

Comment: Yes. ... ... ...    .